# Parse.com pinInBackground ParseException

Tags: android, sqlite, parse-platform

i'm using the following code to save an object and pin it to the local datastore:

```
final ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("freunde");
ParseObject objspieler = ParseObject.createWithoutData("_User", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId().toString());
ParseObject objfreund = ParseObject.createWithoutData("_User", id);
testObject.put("spielerid", objspieler);
testObject.put("freundid", objfreund);               
 testObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            testObject.pinInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    progress.dismiss();
                                    llfreunde.removeAllViews();
                                    getfriends(1);
                                } else {
                                    progress.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

after i run the code, pinInBackground throws following exception:

```
bolts.AggregateException: There were 3 exceptions.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: ParseObjects.className, ParseObjects.objectId (code 2067)
```

i've no idea how to fix this! thanks for any help! i'm using Parse 1.10.1

thanks

Comment: Looks like a query problem. What is in the `getfriends()` method?

Comment: getfriends cant be the problem because the exception is before i call getfriends(1), saveinbackground works fine, after that the pininbackground throws the exception!

Comment: Kind of my point - it would just pass an exception to the pinInBackground if the problem happened there. Meaning it must be within the callback the problem occur. Leading me to suspect getFriends(1).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is part of the problem, but instead of storing id's you could create pointers by changing:

```
final ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("freunde");
ParseObject objspieler = ParseObject.createWithoutData("_User", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId().toString());
ParseObject objfreund = ParseObject.createWithoutData("_User", id);
testObject.put("spielerid", objspieler);
testObject.put("freundid", objfreund);
```

To:

```
ParseUser freund; // assuming you have looked up the User object of the friend

final ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("freunde");
testObject.put("spieler", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
testObject.put("freund", freund);
```

But is not clear to me why you create this object? I mean, you could simply store an array of friend pointers in the User object.

**Why**

Now creating a useful query to obtain information about both users is much easier:

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("freunde");
query.whereEqualTo("spieler", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
query.include("freund");

List<ParseObject> freunde = query.find();
for (ParseObject freund: freunde) {
    ParseUser freundUser = freund.getParseObject("freund");
}
```

Note this is just sketched code showing the idea. The obvious gain is that you do not need to look up the pointer seperately. It is immediadely available in the result set from the query.

Comment: if a table "freunde" which contains 3 columns (objectid, spielerid<Pointer User>, freundid<Pointer User>) and the saveinbackground works fine so the data module looks fine i think...

Comment: ok, well right .. still, you dont need to do `createWithoutData`, just pass the ParseUser directly.

Comment: thx for your comment... now it works half the time ;) sometimes i get the same error, sometimes the local datastore returns 0 and sometimes all works fine... strange

Comment: thx for your edit but i dont need to query the data, i need to SAVE a new friend to parse and to my local datastore!

Comment: but maybe i dont realy undestand what pininbackground does... when i query for "freunde" and include some columns from "Users" and then i call pinAllinBackground, what will be saved locally? "freunde" only or also the "User" class? when the "User" class also is saved locally maybe my Unique exception comes from the "User" pininbackground? my main goal for this is to query the "freunde" at the first time from parse and then only query the local datastore. if someone add a friend i will add the friend locally and on parse but only query for firends locally!

Comment: I think maybe you should try to pin first and then save online. Though still not sure what causes you the error. How do you obtain the id of the friend ?